# JPA- No Persistence provider for EntityManager for MSAccess DB

Tags: jpa, ms-access-2007

Im trying to use JPA to connect to a MS access DB using a JDBC:ODBC connection. Here is my Persistance.xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="DSRJPA">
    <provider>oracle.toplink.essentials.ejb.cmp3.EntityManagerFactoryProvider</provider>
    <class>com.entity.AccessEntity</class>
    <properties>
    <property name="toplink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:odbc:MSAccessDB"/>
    <property name="toplink.jdbc.user" value="admin"/>
    <property name="toplink.jdbc.driver" value="sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"/>
    <property name="toplink.jdbc.password" value="admin"/>
    <property name="toplink.jdbc.read-connections.min" value="1"/>   
    <property name="toplink.jdbc.write-connections.min" value="1"/> 
    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

But when i run the code, i get this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named DSRJPA:  The following providers:
oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider
oracle.toplink.essentials.ejb.cmp3.EntityManagerFactoryProvider
Returned null to createEntityManagerFactory.

    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:154)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:83)
    at com.test.Access.main(Access.java:19)
```

Please throw me some light on this error.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you sure your persistence.xml is picked up? Is it named properly, and placed in a META-INF folder which in turn is in the root of your class path (directly inside your jar file or in /WEB-INF/classes/ if it's a war file)?

Comment: Indeed it looks JPA cannot find the persistence unit. Is your file called Persistance.xml or Persist*e*nce.xml ( isn't there a typo?)

Comment: The file's name & its location is /DSRJPA/src/META-INF/persistence.xml. Its present under the correct folder structure, but i continue to get the error while running it.
Note : Im using a JPA project type in IBM Rad 7.5.

Answer (score 0):

Have you referenced your persistence unit in the class?

i.e.

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("DSRJPA");
```